# What does volatility process mean and how is it different from volatility?

Tags: volatility, yield-curve, volatility-surface, heath-jarrow-morton

I have been reading the paper "[Bridging P-Q Modeling Divide with Factor HJM Modeling Framework](https://deliverypdf.ssrn.com/delivery.php?ID=304031003022085009001115067010100092100062053015068020110122115088005087072070120100121033016010020011028024096112069119112071117006094054007092016001088090068127028057026071084003086009103085074105122079023118072124124103089098103093127097104110091064&EXT=pdf&INDEX=TRUE)" by Lyashenko and Goncharov (2022). On Equation 5 of page 4 of the paper, I came across the volatility process **$\Sigma_{t}$** which is a **K** x **N** matrix where K is the dimension of basis vector and N is the dimension of Brownian motion. Assuming I have the data for spot rates at many maturities and at every time, how can I find this volatility process term?

I know that it can't be the same as volatility of spot rate or the forward rate. For example, given the screenshot below from page 18 of the paper, I have $R_{t}$ and can find out $B_{R}$. The issue is to find out the volatility processes  $\Sigma_{t}$ or $\Sigma_{t}^{R}$.

[image]